# Extract tar.gz file using Perl script

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I am doing a Perl script about extracting tar.gz file with specified location but when I run this code of mine.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use Archive::Tar;
  use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);

  my $input = "sample.tar.gz";
  my $tar   = Archive::Tar->new($input);
  my @files = $tar->list_files;

  my $output_dir = '/var';
  foreach my $file (@files) {

my $extracted_file = catdir($output_dir, $file);
$tar->extract_file($file, $extracted_file);

if ($file =~ /\.rpm\z/ /\.sh\z/ /\.gz\z/) {
    open my $fh, '<', $extracted_file or do { warn "$0: Can't open file $file: $!"; next };
    while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
         do something with $line
                 }
                         close $fh;
                             }
                             }
```

the file name of my script is "extract.pl" so when I run this script. I got this error

```
 ./extract.pl: line 1: use: command not found

 ./extract.pl: line 2: use: command not found

 ./extract.pl: line 4: use: command not found

 ./extract.pl: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('

 ./extract.pl: line 5: `use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);'
```

Can anyone help me this out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options; One) the first line of your script should be (to search the PATH first) `#!/usr/bin/env perl` or directly to the path of your perl install (mine is at `#!/usr/bin/perl`).

Finally, Two) by invoking your script with `perl`

```
perl extract.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

Please give perl interpreter in first line using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

or any path in which perl is installed

Or executed the script as

```
perl extract.pl
```

Your script is being interpreted inside your `default shell` which I believe is bash

so it’s not able to recognize `use` as there is no such keyword/command in bash or any shell.
hence the error

```
use command not found
```

Comment: I've tried adding the shebang but there are still errors. and the error remaining is ./extract.pl: line 5: `use File::Spec::Functions qw(catdir);'.

Comment: @user3534255 try putting spaces before and after ( )

Comment: Are you sure the error message is identical to the contents of line 5?

Answer (score -1):

A shebang ist missing, telling which interpreter should be used by your script.

Please add:

**#!/bin/perl**

at the first line.